# Location parameter in awesome-cv is too short

Tags: xetex, cv, awesome-cv

The full address of my university is too long to fit within one line with the default formatting settings. Here is my current output:
[image]

However, I need the location to fit in one line as it is messing with the formatting. I have tried tinkering with the `\cventry` command, but I have found nothing. The code is below:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

the formatting that is specific to the location is:

```
\newcommand*{\entrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}
```

Edit: This is how I call cventry

```
  \cventry
    {Bachelor of Computer Science (BCS) Honours, Software Engineering Stream} % Degree
    {Carleton University} % Institution
    {1125 Colonel By Dr, Ottawa ON, Canada K1S 5B6} % Location
    {Sep. 2022 - Apr. 2026} % Date(s)
    {
    \textbf{Courses:} Accelerated Intro to Computer Science I and II, Intro to Systems Programming, Discrete Structures I, Calculus I, Linear Algebra I, \newline Critical Thinking, Intro to Cognitive Science, Intro to Film Studies.
    }
    % \vspace{-\baselineskip}

%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}
```

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, you're allowing 4.5cm for the location, which seems like it should be enough.  How are you actually using `\cventry` to create that entry?

Comment: Hey @Teepeemm! I just edited my question.

Comment: I can't get this to compile.  Could you extend it to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497)?

Comment: Hey @Teepeemm! Here is the MWE: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/sydyspnvhzff). Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add after `\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{awesome-cv}`

Will expand the left column to allow longer addresses.

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
    \vspace{-2.0mm}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{0.6\textwidth} R{0.4\textwidth}}
        \ifempty{#2#3}
        {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
            \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
    \end{tabular*}%
}
```

[image: a]